# pass arguments to java through ant

Tags: java, ant

I want to pass command line arguments to my java program that is invoked through a fake ant (we have our own ant script in perl which at some point calls the actual ant). So what I want to do is invoke my program like this :

> `./ant program_name arg1 arg2`

Right now I have an ant target for my program but instead of passing the arguments from the command line I am hard-coding them into the build file like this :

> `<arg line="arg1 arg2"/>`

Any ideas on how can I use variables in the build file and load them from the command line arguments and then use them in my java program ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest might be to have your script turn then into system properties through `-D`.

Your ant build file can then use those to set ant properties that can be set in the `<arg>` tag (or referenced directly, although my preference would be to set ant properties, but that may be more out of habit than for any technical reason).

Comment: I dont know much about ant. but the ant script that we have is calling the real ant with something like this : my $cmdline = "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx512m -Djava.ext.dirs=\"$ENV{EXT_DIRS}\" -Dant.home=$ENV{ANT_HOME} org.apache.tools.ant.Main -emacs $inp"; where $inp is the whole command that we give at the command line. Is that what you were talking about ?

Comment: @comatose Probably. My approach meant to split `$inp` and turn each into named `-D` parameters. I'm not sure how else to access command-line params in the build file, although if you spent some time with the Ant manual it might be really easy--I've just never done it.